# FFMPEG wavelet transform

Tags: ffmpeg, dwt

What library should I add to use DWT? `j2k_dwt.h` is too old and I can't find what library is using in FFMPEG API now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The updated version of j2k_dwt.c seems to be **libavcodec/jpeg2000dwt.c**

[GitHub link](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/jpeg2000dwt.c)